# Only allow simple products to be added

Tags: configuration, products-management

Is there a way to disable all the product types in the "add product" -> "product type"-dropdown, so that the shop owner only can add simple products?

thx in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Settings` and replace the product type dropdown with a hidden input.
Remove this:

```
 $fieldset->addField('product_type', 'select', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Type'),
    'name'  => 'type',
    'value' => '',
    'values'=> Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray()
 ));
```

and add this:

```
$fieldset->addField('product_type', 'hidden', array(
    'name'  => 'type',
    'value' => 'simple',
));
```